# What is the neatest way to go from recursion to iteration when there is logic after the recursive call?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration, graph-algorithm

Say I had a method like the following where the call to `tidy()` had to be after the call to `recurse()`:

```
void recurse(Node node)
{
    foreach(Node child in node.children)
    {
        recurse(child);
    }

    tidy(node);
}
```

What would be the neatest way of converting this to an iterative method?

Comment: As long as it recurses more than once each iteration you can't. You can replace it with looping construct + explicit stack, but as long as the stack grows in size I'd call it recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code of an iterative version:

```
void iterate(Node node){
  Vector<Node> stack;

  stack.push(node);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < stack.size(); ++i){
    foreach(Node child in stack[i].children){
      stack.push(child);
    }
  }

  while(!stack.empty()){
    tidy(stack.top());
    stack.pop();
  }
}
```

This version calls `tidy` in the same order as your recursive one does.

Comment: @RecurseYouJack: Sylwesters comment is actually quite true. You can always exchange a recursive algorithm with an iterative one, if you use an explicit stack instead of the call stack. However, I don't know whether he meant "equivalent" or "equal" by == (it is the first).

Comment: @Sylwester, That may be the case, but this was what I was after. Would you recommend I call this something like "stack-based recursion" instead?